# Prompt user but show character after the prompt cursor

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to prompt a user to enter a percentage score and press enter, but I want it to look like this:

> Enter the percentage score:_%

The underscore is the blinking cursor.

After the user enters the number:

> Enter the percentage score:90%

The normal command for a prompt is `Console.ReadLine` but I don't know how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
Dim a, b As Integer
a = Console.CursorLeft
b = Console.CursorTop
Console.Write("  %")
Console.SetCursorPosition(a, b)
Console.ReadLine
```

Comment: Thanks Mate this is what i wanted!! *6 fake internet points for you*

Comment: how do i stop it from overwriting the percentage symbol?

Comment: If you want to keep the % you need to write it after each input, so instead of Console.ReadLine, use Console.ReadKey and then write the % to the new position.

Answer (score 0):

Not really pretty, but you can use Console.SetCursorPosition(int left, int top) to manipulate this.

For example:

```
`Console.Write("Enter the percentage score:")
Console.SetCursorPosition(30, Console.CursorTop)            
Console.Write("%")
//Then reset position
Console.SetCursorPosition(27, Console.CursorTop)            
Console.ReadKey`
```

Also note that the position between : and the cursor is static, so you can't input 100 without overwriting the % symbol.